# 縦長画像を含むWebページを印刷すると、画像が2ページ目に出力されてしまう。

Tags: html, css, 印刷

以下のHTMLを印刷すると、`.test-2`(ピンク部分)は1ページ目に出力されますが、
`.test-3`(パープル部分)の画像は2ページ目に出力されてしまいます。

1枚目の画像（ブラウザでの表示）のように、1ページ目の`.test-2`(ピンク部分)の直下に、
`.test-3`(パープル部分)の画像をくっつけて出力したいです。

CSS の記述方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

※ 画像の縦サイズが1ページの縦サイズを超える場合に発生します。

```
<html lang="ja">
<body>
<div class="test-1">
   <div class="test-2" style="border: 1px solid;">
      1ページ内の、このdivの直下に画像を表示したい。
   </div>
   <div class="test-3" style="border: 1px solid;">
      <img src="./test.png" alt="1ページの高さを超えるサイズの画像">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: 1_divの直下に画像をくっつけて表示したい]
[image: 2_印刷プレビューを表示すると、画像部分は2ページ目からはじまってしまう]
[image: 3_検証用の画像]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img>` は断片化しないので、`<img>` の代わりに `<div>` などの `background-image` として画像を表示するのがよいでしょう。

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break/#possible-breaks

> Some content is not fragmentable, for example many types of replaced elements [CSS2] (such as images or video), scrollable elements, or a single line of text content. Such content is considered monolithic: it contains no possible break points.

Comment: ありがとうございます、とても勉強になりました！　`background-image` を使用した際の疑問が湧いてきましたので、別件としてポストさせていただきました。もしおわかりになりましたらアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93379/background-image-%e3%81%8c%e6%8c%87%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f-div-%e3%81%a7-%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e7%9a%84%e3%81%ab-height-%e3%82%92%e6%8c%87%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%82%92%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84