# background-image が指定された div で、自動的に height を指定する方法を知りたい

Tags: html, css

#### やりたいこと

- background-image, max-width が指定された div で、自動的に height を明示する方法を知りたい。

  - max-width を超える場合は、 max-width まで縮小したい。
- できれば css だけで実現したい。

#### 前提条件

- 画像のサイズは不定で、小さいこともあれば大きいこともある。
- div の max-width は 400px を指定。

#### 参考コード

- この例では、横幅 800px の画像は max-width の 400px まで縮小されるため、`height:1000px`に相当する値をセットしたい。

```
<html lang="ja">
<body>
<div style="background-image:url(./test.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; max-width: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: 検証用の画像_800x2000px]

Comment: `div`でなく`img`を使うことはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。　`img`が使えないという縛りがあっての質問でした。　前提として書いていなくてすみませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像の縦横比が一定であれば [`aspect-ratio` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)を指定するだけで可能かと思います。

縦横比が一定ではないなら、CSSだけではできないと思われます。[`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)で対象の画像をロードして `naturalWidth` `naturalHeight` から計算して `<div>` 要素の `height` プロパティを更新します。

Comment: `aspect-ratio` というプロパティを知らなかったので、大変勉強になりました。　ただ、今回は縦横比が一定ではありませんので、jsで実装する方向にしようと思います。　ありがとうございました！